# How to count the number of user entered data in each column except null?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have multiple columns inputs DATE field in a table connected to sql DB. Now I need to summarize and display the number of user entries to each column. NULL values should not be counted.

I can count the number of rows. But not the entries. Please help. EX: If I have 10 rows in a column, and the user entered only 2 inputs so far, Then the output should be shown as 2 in another table.

Here is my current full code:

```
    <?php
include_once('confiq.php');
$sql="SELECT * FROM fiberexcel";
$records=mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
?>

<?php
$page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$sec = "10";
?>

<style type="text/css">

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}


td{
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}
</style> 

<html>
<head>
    <title>DASHBOARD</title>
    <div id="home"><a href="index.html"><img src="./img/home.png"></img></a></div>
</head>
<body>
    <table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" style="font-size:11px; font-family:verdana;" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>TITLE</th>
            <th>TARGETS</th>
            <th>ACTUALS</th>
            <th>COMPLETED %</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
        <td>Sent to Contractors for Quotation</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>

        <td>Count</td> 
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>SO Approval for JFS Requested</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>

        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>SO Approval for JFS Received</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>

        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>JFS Done</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>

        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Drawing Submited OFN to SAQ</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>Drawing Submited OFN to SAQ</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Tech Evaluation Given to DE</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>All Quotations Recieved</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Mail confirmation to work start without PO from DE</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Contractor PO received from DE</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Work Approval Request</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>



        <tr><td>Work Approval received</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>IBW Started</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>IBW Completed</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Hand over to contractor for WLA / Implementation</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>Request sent to Authority</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>

        <tr><td>Estimate received by Dialog</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>       


        <tr><td>System PR Requested for WLA</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>   


        <tr><td>System PO done</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>   


        <tr><td>Documents sent to Fin</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>   


        <tr><td>Payment Received from Fin</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>   


        <tr><td>Payment submitted to Contractor</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Payment Submitted to Authority</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>OSP Work Started</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>OSP Work Completed</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>


        <tr><td>Cable Blowing / Splicing and Testing Completed</td>
        <?php
        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rows = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>"  .$rows[0] ." </td>";
        ?>
        <td>Count</td>
        <td>Count</td>
        </tr>



    </thead>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: _"I have multiple columns inputs DATE field in a table"_ No you haven't - at least not in the table in your example. And why on earth are you executing the same query for each row of the table? O.o

Comment: @andreas.. I have a user input table connected to SQL DB. It contains 64+ columns. What I request is to get the count of number of entries in each column. Like a dashboard and display in a separate table . How can i do that?

Comment: I have repeated the same code in order to display number of entries in each column under the titles. How can I post a photo/code of mine to display?

Comment: Please check https://jsfiddle.net/gratuggz/

Comment: This is a good question, but I think the CSS is irrelevant for this question. Can you edit your question to make sure it only contains the code part which is relevant for the question so it will be easier to digest for readers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//$i = 1;
while ($fiberexcel=mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)){
}
?>
<?php
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
$TARGETS = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
?>

<!--Quotation11-->
        <tr>
        <td>Sent to Contractors for Quotation</td>
        <?php echo "<td>"  .$TARGETS[0] ." </td>";

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel WHERE Quotation11 ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $ACTUALS = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>" .$ACTUALS[0] . "</td>";

        $pers = ROUND($ACTUALS[0]/$TARGETS[0] *100 ) . "%";
        echo "<td>" .$pers . "</td>";
        ?>
        </tr>

<!--ApprovalJFSRequest13-->
        <tr><td>SO Approval for JFS Requested</td>
        <?php echo "<td>"  .$TARGETS[0] ." </td>";

        $query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fiberexcel WHERE ApprovalJFSRequest13 ";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $ACTUALS = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo "<td>" . $ACTUALS[0] . "</td>" ;

        $pers = ($ACTUALS[0]/$TARGETS[0]) *100 . "%";
        echo "<td>" .$pers . "</td>";
        ?>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Since you accepted this answer I would like to ask you to explain what you did for the sake of future visitors.

Comment: Sure. Will do :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to `count` the number of different values of a given column in your `table` you can do it like this:

```
select sum(foo)
from
(select 1 as foo
from fiberexcel
group by givencolumn) t
```

The inner query will create a group for each possible value in `fiberexcel.givencolumn` and select 1 as `foo`. Since for each group 1 is correlated to it, the `sum` of `foo` will result in the value you need. You can do this for any columns.

EDIT:

Let's suppose you have a table T and you have a column C in this table. When you are interested to know aggregate information based on different C values, then you have a need of grouping:

```
select C
from T
group by C
```

The result of this query will contain groups of T on C. Let's suppose you are interested about the number of each possible C elements in T. You will need to do a count in that case:

```
select C, count(*) as element_number
from T
group by C
```

Now, in our case we are interested to know the number of groups (the number of different values), so we do a grouping and select 1 for each group and add them. But it can be solved differently if it is more understandable/sympathetic for you. Example:

```
select count(*)
from
(select givencolumn
 from fiberexcel
 group by givencolumn) t
```

Comment: Can you please explain little more, please? I'm unable to understand :(

Comment: @Sugs I have added further explanation to clarify the answer. If this is still not clear, then please ask concrete questions so I many address the unclarities.

Comment: Thank you so much Lajos Arpad. I'm sorry for the delay reply. I tried the above code and I ended up as below answer. Thanks again :)